# bit manipulation in C, setting the least significant bit

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BYTETOBINARYPATTERN "%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d"

#define BYTETOBINARY(byte) \
    (byte & 0x80 ? 1 : 0), \
    (byte & 0x40 ? 1 : 0), \
    (byte & 0x20 ? 1 : 0), \
    (byte & 0x10 ? 1 : 0), \
    (byte & 0x08 ? 1 : 0), \
    (byte & 0x04 ? 1 : 0), \
    (byte & 0x02 ? 1 : 0), \
    (byte & 0x01 ? 1 : 0)

#define PRINTBIN(x) printf(BYTETOBINARYPATTERN, BYTETOBINARY(x));

void printarr(unsigned char *p);
void setlsbs(unsigned char *p, unsigned char b0);
unsigned char getlsbs(unsigned char *p);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unsigned char arr[7];
    unsigned char byte0, byte1;
    int i;

    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Error.Invalid arguments.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    //seed random
    srandom(atoi(argv[1]));

    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        arr[i] = random() % 255+1;

    byte0 = random() % (255 + 1);

    printarr(arr);

    printf("\nbyte0: ");
    PRINTBIN(byte0);
    printf("  %d\n\n",byte0);

    setlsbs(arr, byte0);

    printarr(arr);

    byte1 = getlsbs(arr);

    printf("\nbyte1: ");
    PRINTBIN(byte1);
    printf("   %d\n\n", byte1);

    return 0;
}

void printarr(unsigned char *p)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        PRINTBIN(p[i]);
        printf("   %d\n", p[i]);
    }
}

void setlsbs(unsigned char *p, unsigned char b0)
{
    int i, counter;
    unsigned char x;
    x = b0;

    for (i = 0, counter = 1; i < 8; i++, counter++) {
        p[i] &= 0xFE;
        x &= 0x01;
        p[i] |= x;
        x = b0;
        x >>= counter;
    }
}

unsigned char getlsbs(unsigned char *p)
{
    int i, counter;
    unsigned char b0 = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        p[i] &= 0x01;
        b0 |= p[i];
        b0 <<= 1;
    }
    return b0;
}
```

I am trying to set `byte1` with the least signifcant digits of the elements in the array. For example, the rightmost bit of `p[0]` will be the leftmost bit of byte 1. The rightmost byte of `p[1]` will be the second bit of byte 1 and so forth. The code works for some numbers but it doesnt for others and I cant quite figure it out. I think my algorithm is right.

Running the code:

```
John Doe@DESKTOP-QFEGQQD ~/learn
$ ./lab11 50
00110101   53
10100110   166
01101101   109
11001001   201
10111101   189
01000101   69
10010011   147
10000001   129

byte0: 01011001  89

00110101   53
10100110   166
01101100   108
11001001   201
10111101   189
01000100   68
10010011   147
10000000   128

byte1: 00110100   52
```

Byte1 should equal Byte0.

Comment: Say what? Show input and desired output

Comment: Can you reduce the code? The problem you are speaking of can be demonstrated with much less noise.

Comment: In `getlsbs`, `<<=` should be first and then `|=` the new bit.

Comment: `random() % 255+1` is that intentional? The spacing (or lack thereof) suggests it's supposed to be `random() % 256`

Answer (score 3):

`arr` is declared as 7-element array, while you are accessing it as 8-element. It results in undefined behavior, which explains "sometimes works, sometimes not".

Comment: While your remark is correct, it is not the explanation for the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You should of course fix the definition of the array `arr` in `main` to be 8 bytes long:

```
unsigned char arr[8];
```

Furthermore, your method in `getlsbs` is incorrect: you should shift the byte **before** or-ing the next bit, otherwise you lose the top bit and always set the low bit to 0.  You do not need to modify the argument buffer for that, it is a nasty side-effect.  Also note that your algorithm actually transposes the bits from `b0` into `b1`.  It is not obvious from your comment that you really mean that.

Here is a modified version:

```
unsigned char getlsbs(unsigned char const *p) {
    int i;
    unsigned char b0 = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        b0 = (b0 << 1) | (p[i] & 1);
    }
    return b0;
}
```

I had to reindent your code to make it readable.  Do not use TABs in your source files, and forget the silly `/* end if */` comments.  The `BYTETOBINARY` macro should be fixed too: you should protect `byte` with parentheses in the expansion.  It does not cause a bug here, but `BYTETOBINARY(1|2)` would fail.

Comment: Clear, succinct and to the point with additional valid style suggestions. Well done.